# How to get external memory allocation in Honeycomb?

Tags: android, memory, external, allocation, android-3.0-honeycomb

In pre-Honeycomb versions of Android I tracked external allocation of memory  `VMRuntime.getRuntime().getExternalBytesAllocated()` or with `Debug.*ExternalAllocSize()`. Now VMRuntime is not available in Honeycomb and all `Debug.*ExternalAllocSize()` methods returns 0 as they remains only for compatibility reason.
Anyone knows how to get external memory allocation in Honeycomb?

Answer (score 3):

The external memory allocation feature was removed entirely from Honeycomb.

All allocations now appear on the managed heap.